# Drools MVEL Dialect - Semi-Colon Requirement

Tags: drools, mvel

I am just curious as to why my Eclipse Drools compiler (6.5.0) requires semi-colons at the end of statements in the For loop, as below:

```
Map businessRulesRequest = $root.containsKey("BusinessRulesRequest") ? $root.get("BusinessRulesRequest") : null
Map quoteRequest = businessRulesRequest!=null && businessRulesRequest.containsKey("QuoteRequest") ? businessRulesRequest.get("QuoteRequest") : null
List resultsByKey = quoteRequest!=null && quoteRequest.containsKey("resultsByKey") ? quoteRequest.get("resultsByKey") : new ArrayList()

for (Map search : resultsByKey) {
    Map searchInfo = (search.containsKey("searchInfo") ? search.get("searchInfo") : null);
    String searchName = searchInfo!=null && searchInfo.containsKey("searchName") ? searchInfo.get("searchName").toString() : "";
    List results = (searchName=="quotesMotor" && search.containsKey("results") ? search.get("results") : new ArrayList());
}
```

If I remove the semi-colons from the first or second lines in the For loop, I get an "unexpected token" error, but not if I remove it from the last line in the loop.

Is it due to Drools evaluating RHS lines as a single statement and so they must be separated inside any loops?

Note: I understand it is not best practice to code assuming semi-colons are not required, however I came across this issue while experimenting and am just interested to know the reason for the compiler error. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I guess the answer is because of MVEL itself. Drools may be delegating the entire chunk of code to MVEL to evaluate and execute.

According to [this guide](https://github.com/imona/tutorial/wiki/MVEL-Guide#multiple-statements), in MVEL the use of a semi-colon is not mandatory in cases where you have 1 statement, or in the last statement of a script.

Hope it helps,

Comment: Thanks, and yes it looks like it treats "if", "for", etc contents as a single line, so if semi-colons are not added to the end of lines it's treated as a single statement. Best to add semi-colons on all lines I reckon, to be safe.